As John steps out of the car
I provided the following context for one of my earlier questions:
John's life has been hectic recently, so he's driven to a remote village to take a break from city life. Peter, an inhabitant of that village, sees John's car. As John steps out of the car, Peter approaches him. They have the following conversation.
I wonder if I used the simple present "steps" correctly here, and if "is stepping" would also be correct in this context. Thanks.

yes, it would also be correct

Yes, both options are grammatically correct, and they mean the same thing. But my instinct is that steps is a bit more punchy than is stepping. Sometimes a writer will tell a story in the present tense to give a more dramatic and immediate feeling. It helps us to imagine we are right there with the action as it unfolds. For that reason I would possibly choose steps as a parallel to approaches. (But note this is a personal stylistic choice, not a grammatical one.)
